# ¿Por que no hace la función PHP Formulario de registro?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli, php7

Estoy intentando crear un formulario de registro, la conexión a la base de datos está todo bien, pero el formulario no responde, donde está el código para registrar al usuario lo veo bien y al hacerlo me aseguré que cada etiqueta esté bien al igual que el código, no llego a encontrar el error, a que se debe el error? como puedo solucionarlo?
Agradezco la ayuda y gracias de ante mano, un saludo.

*Este es el código del index

```
<?php

    if (!empty($_POST["sending"]))
    {
        if (!empty($_POST["username"]) || !empty($_POST["email"]) || !empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            echo("Tienes que rellenar todos los campos");
        }

        include('conectardb.php');
        include('redirect.inc.php');

        $error = false;

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
        if ($stmt->execute()) $error = true;
        $stmt->close();
        $con->close();

        if ($error) die("Ya existe un usuario con ese nombre.");
        redirect("index.php");
    }
    else
    {

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body translate="no">

<form action="login.php" method="POST" id="msform">

<ul id="progressbar">
<li class="active">Crea tu cuenta</li>
<li class="active">Ingresar</li>
</ul>

<fieldset style="transform: scale(0.8); position: absolute; opacity: 0; display: none;">
<h2 class="fs-title">Crea tu cuenta</h2>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" >
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" aria-autocomplete="list" >
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" >
<input type="submit" name="sending" class="submit action-button" value="Registrar">
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Ingresar">
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="display: block; left: 0%; opacity: 1;">
<h2 class="fs-title">Ingresar</h2>
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email">
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Registrarte">
<input type="submit" name="sending1" class="submit action-button" value="Ingresar">
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

*Esto tengo en la conexión de la base de datos: "conectardb.php"

```
<?php 
    function conectar()
    {
        $user = "root"; 
        $pass = ""; 
        $server = "localhost"; 
        $db = "Tripex";
        $con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Error al conectar" .mysql_error());
        return $con;
    }
 ?>
```

Hice una prueba con un simple "echo" para averiguar si funcionaba la base de datos y está todo perfecto, sigo sin encontrar la falla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la línea

```php
if (!empty($_POST["username"]) || !empty($_POST["email"]) || !empty($_POST["password"]))
```

debería ser:

```php
if (empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
```

y que la línea

```php
if ($stmt->execute()) $error = true;
```

debería ser

```php
if (!$stmt->execute()) $error = true;
```

---

En el archivo `conectardb.php` tienes una función que conecta y devuelve el "manejador" de la conexión.

El problema es que no veo que llames a esa función en ningún sitio.

Antes de `$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users ...` pon esto:

```php
$con = conectar();
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora funciona parte del código, sin embargo ahora me tira este error:
Notice: Undefined variable: con 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Este es la linea 15:
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

Comment: Revisa tu código de conexión, puede que no se esté realizando correctamente la conexión y es por eso que devuelve null.

Comment: Sí, tiene pinta de que algo falla en `conectardb.php`. Al salir de ese archivo, `$con` no está definida.

Comment: Acabo de acutalizar, puse como está en conectardb.php

Comment: Ok, edito la respuesta.

Comment: ¡Gracias @jotaelesalinas!